# Only ngb-modal-backdrop showing, modal not working, while integrating mattlewis92 Angular 6.0+ calendar

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap, ng-template, angular-calendar

Integrated [Angular 6.0+ calendar](https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/) to school project (I'm a web development beginner), all other functionalities are working, but when opening up a modal, only the modal backdrop activates. Tried disabling the `ngb-modal-backdrop` CSS in the browser, but the modal still didn't show.

Here is a screenshot of inspecting the page, after I have opened the modal and only the backdrop is showing.
[image: Here is a screenshot of inspecting the page, after I have opened the modal and only the backdrop is showing.]

From what I've understood, this might be a Bootstrap bug, but I'm not sure. So perhaps some custom CSS will fix it?

I haven't changed any code from the original project, but this is the part responsible for the modal in the **calendar.component.html** file:

```html
<ng-template #modalContent let-close="close">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title">Event action occurred</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" (click)="close()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div>
      Action:
      <pre>{{ modalData?.action }}</pre>
    </div>
    <div>
      Event:
      <pre>{{ modalData?.event | json }}</pre>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="close()">
      OK
    </button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Which boostrap library are you using? Angular Bootstrap? Or just the native Bootstrap?

Comment: how are you loading the bootstrap CSS?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not 100% sure, but in the calendar component HTML file, we have these: <link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-css-only@4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/font-awesome@4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/angular-calendar@0.26.11/css/angular-calendar.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/flatpickr@4.5.2/dist/flatpickr.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: We have both native Bootstrap and Angular Bootstrap in our package-lock.json file, I'm honestly not sure @wentjun - where should I look to give you a better answer?